# Exception when accessing a web service using axis2 (Sales Force) in IBM Websphere 8

Tags: java, websphere, apache-axis, salesforce, ssl-certificate

I am trying to integrate with sales force. I have a sample runnning on weblogic but fails on WAS(tried only on WAS 8). This is the error I get. It says that i have a certificate that is not trusted. Can I disable the certificate chack? I dont even know why this certificate is being used. The stack is very long(overflowing :)) sry about that.

```
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:505 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:570)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:399)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:226)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:514)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:506 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.sforce.soap.partner.SforceServiceStub.login(SforceServiceStub.java:3447)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.leads.integration.adapters.SalesForce.UpdateExternalSystem.login(UpdateExternalSystem.java:62)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.leads.integration.adapters.SalesForce.UpdateExternalSystem.upsertSFAObject(UpdateExternalSystem.java:93)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.leads.integration.publisher.transmitters.SFATransmitter.send(SFATransmitter.java:21)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.leads.integration.publisher.IntegrationMgr.transmit(IntegrationMgr.java:79)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.leads.integration.publisher.listeners.PostRuleEngineListenerImpl.transformAndTransmit(PostRuleEngineListenerImpl.java:78)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.leads.integration.publisher.IntegrationMgr.findListenerAndPost(IntegrationMgr.java:116)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.leads.integration.publisher.IntegrationMgr.postEvents(IntegrationMgr.java:111)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:507 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.marketsoft.ruleengine.InMemoryRuleAgent.run(InMemoryRuleAgent.java:120)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:769)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.msg.StAXMessageProvider.throwXMLStreamException(StAXMessageProvider.java:67)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLStreamWriterImpl.close(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:621)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl$XMLStreamWriterProxy.close(XMLOutputFactoryImpl.java:150)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamWriterWrapper.close(XMLStreamWriterWrapper.java:46)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:508 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.close(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:188)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:197)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     ... 30 more
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:22)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:192)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:176)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:53)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:464)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:509 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:545)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:530)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:79)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:772)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.k.write(k.java:3)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:76)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:134)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:191)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:510 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:134)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.serializer.StAXWriter.flush(StAXWriter.java:65)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLStreamWriterImpl.close(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:613)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     ... 35 more
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:113)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:61)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:22)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:100)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.checkServerTrusted(pc.java:15)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:511 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.core.WSX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(WSX509TrustManager.java:362)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:5)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     ... 48 more
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:98)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     ... 54 more
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:512 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:595)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:595)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     ... 56 more
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:298)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
[1/20/12 17:31:17:513 IST] 0000002a SystemErr     R     ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the above issue, please add the VeriSign root certificate into your trust store (google it and you will receive numerous hits)

If you want to bypass it altogether, you will need to use non-SSL (I dont know whether that will be an option).

Comment: but it works on Weblogic without any certificate addition. So, whats so special about WAS?

Comment: WebSphere does not trust any SSL certificates by default. Weblogic may automatically trust some known CA certs. To do it non-SSL, the service you're hitting must provide an http URL instead of an https one. It's likely that's not an option, though. Most services that provide SSL actually depend on it to protect the messages from snooping.

Comment: You will need to check whats setup in the WebSphere trust store and whether a trust store is even setup for it! If it works on WebLogic (as dbreaux has  correctly pointed out) it simply proves that the WebLogic has the correct entries in its trust store.
Non-SSL is only an option if the end-point provides it. If you are accessing a vendor (Salesforce) url, I doubt if they will provide you one.

Comment: ok! I will add this certificate as trusted one to my WAS. Thanks a lot!